# How to send value to oracle database?

Tags: php, oracle

I need to send a invoice number to the third party(Oracle database) and they will respond me in response to the same i tried to create connection with them and i got a successful result but right now i need to send a SQL query to get a response but unfortunately i dont know how to send that.
Here is my connection and query code that i used:-

```
<?php
  $db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 83.111.41.30)(PORT = 1536)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=TEST)))" ;

  if($c = OCILogon("XXWEBSITE", "xxwebsite", $db))
  {
    echo 'success';
    $query = "BEGIN 
      P_INV_NUMBER := '34499';
      P_INV_NUM := NULL;
      P_UNIT_NO := NULL;
      P_CUST_NAME := NULL;
      P_INV_DATE := NULL;
      P_TRANS_TYPE := NULL;
      P_CUST_NO := NULL;
      P_OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT := NULL;
      L_ERROR := NULL;
      APPS.XX_AR_CUST_OS_BAL_PKG.XX_AR_CUST_OS_BAL_PROC ( P_INV_NUMBER, P_INV_NUM, P_UNIT_NO, P_CUST_NAME, P_INV_DATE, P_TRANS_TYPE, P_CUST_NO, P_OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT, L_ERROR );
      COMMIT; 
    END;";
      $stid = oci_parse($c, $query);
      $check =  oci_execute($stid);
 print_r($check);
       OCILogoff($c);
     }
  else
  {
      $err = OCIError();
      echo "Connection failed.";
  }
?>
```

the query they asked to send was:-

```
DECLARE 
      P_INV_NUMBER VARCHAR2(32767);
      P_INV_NUM VARCHAR2(32767);
      P_UNIT_NO VARCHAR2(32767);
      P_CUST_NAME VARCHAR2(32767);
      P_INV_DATE DATE;
      P_TRANS_TYPE VARCHAR2(32767);
      P_CUST_NO NUMBER;
      P_OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT NUMBER;
      L_ERROR VARCHAR2(32767);
    BEGIN 
      P_INV_NUMBER := '34499';
      P_INV_NUM := NULL;
      P_UNIT_NO := NULL;
      P_CUST_NAME := NULL;
      P_INV_DATE := NULL;
      P_TRANS_TYPE := NULL;
      P_CUST_NO := NULL;
      P_OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT := NULL;
      L_ERROR := NULL;
      APPS.XX_AR_CUST_OS_BAL_PKG.XX_AR_CUST_OS_BAL_PROC ( P_INV_NUMBER, P_INV_NUM, P_UNIT_NO, P_CUST_NAME, P_INV_DATE, P_TRANS_TYPE, P_CUST_NO, P_OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT, L_ERROR );
      COMMIT; 
    END;
```

How to send these parameters I tried one way but I dont know if its correct. I need to send the above to get the result how can i do that?

Comment: Ddi you try your code? What happened?

Comment: By the way that's not a query. Also in PL/SQL, scalar variables start out null by default, so none of the `:= NULL` assignments do anything. And you can save another line by assigning a value at initialisation instead. And there is no requirement to write PL/SQL in uppercase - it's not COBOL and this isn't 1974.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be better off calling the stored procedure directly through PHP/OCI than trying to do it through a PL/SQL "query":

```
$stid = oci_parse($c, "call apps.xx_ar_cust_os_bal_pkg.xx_ar_cust_os_bal_proc('34499', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)");
oci_execute($stid);
```

If you need to return the results of the stored procedure, then you need to use bind variables:

```
$stid = oci_parse($c, "call apps.xx_ar_cust_os_bal_pkg.xx_ar_cust_os_bal_proc('34499', :inv_num, :unit_no, :cust_name, :inv_date, :trans_type, :cust_no, :outstanding_amount, :err)");
/* Do this for each bind variable */
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":inv_num", $inv_num);
...
oci_execute($stid);
```

**EDIT:** Passing the `P_INV_NUMBER` parameter as a bind variable:

```
$stid = oci_parse($c, "call apps.xx_ar_cust_os_bal_pkg.xx_ar_cust_os_bal_proc(:inv_number, :inv_num, :unit_no, :cust_name, :inv_date, :trans_type, :cust_no, :outstanding_amount, :err)");
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":inv_number", "34499");
/* Do this for each bind variable */
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":inv_num", $inv_num);
...
oci_execute($stid);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since '34499' will vary, it should also be passed as a bind variable (because concatenating text to build up a SQL string can be a security risk, and affect application scalability)

Comment: Definitely, I agree.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will get back to after checking this

Comment: Can you let me know how can i send the P_INV_NUMBER := '34499'; and get respose to that?

Comment: @rahulshukla you can send it directly to the stored proc (as I did above) or you can pass it as a bind variable.

Comment: How can i send another sql query when we get the response to  the invoice number we send?

Comment: @rahulshukla, the same way you send this one: `oci_parse()` for the statement, `oci_bind_by_name()` for each of the variables you need to replace, then `oci_execute()`. If you have a specific query in mind - please ask as another question.